# The essence of $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{P}(A_{n})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A_n=\{1,2,3\dots n\}$
I want to understand what will be the essence of $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{P}(A_{n})$
For example, is the following statement true: $\mathbb{N}\in\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{P}(A_{n})$ ?

Comment: The trick is with the symbol used: when you write $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}$ it seems that tehre is a set $A_{\infty}$ that "obviously" must contain **all** natural numbers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's exactly what confused me. But now I understand that it is not so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\mathcal P(A_n)$ is the set of all sets $M$ such that there is some $n$ such that $M\subseteq A_n$. In this case, we may describe it as the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: So $\mathbb{N}\notin\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathcal{P}(A_{n})$. Right?

Comment: You are right .